# Variant calling without matched normal sample

Tags: sam, snp, gatk, wgs, vcftools

I have WGS .bam files for 3 patients (tumour and its matched derived model namely organoid) but I don't matched normal sample. If I call variants of each patients (tumour and its matched organoid), how I can use read counts at germline heterozygous positions estimated by GATK 3.2-2 to compensate for the absence of matched normal sample? I heard people use dbsnp VCF instead of the matched normal small variant VCF. But, I don't know start from where? which GATK function does that?

> I should mention, Calling SNV and indel in many tools returns vcf but
>   I called copy number by varscan that did not return .vcf output so I
>   am not sure what to do for CNV

Any helps please?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to filter out calls present in dbSNP then use:

```
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
   -T SelectVariants \
   -R reference.fasta \
   -V patient.vcf \
   --discordance dbSNP.vcf \
   -o patient.filtered.vcf
```

`--discordance` will produce calls not present in dbSNP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Devon, Calling SNV and indel in many tools returns vcf but I called copy number by varscan that did not return .vcf output, is this command is applicable yet?

Comment: It's usually best to mention things like that in your post... I presume this will still work, but I can't say I've ever tried.

Comment: https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/article?id=11682

Comment: I heard GenomeAnalysisTK.jar has been replaced. Do you know by which function we can filter a vcf file based on dbSNP?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clue by scatngs

https://github.com/cancerit/ascatNgs/wiki/Human-reference-files-from-1000-genomes-VCFs

and already calculated file is here

ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/cancer/support-files/CPIB/ascatNgs/Human/GRCh37/

Although installing scatngs itself is a big burden